# Given that $ a,b,c$ are positive numbers and $(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)=1$, find the maximum value of $P=ab+bc+ca$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, maxima-minima

I am stuck with this problem:

> Given that $ a,b,c$ are positive numbers and $(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)=1$, find the maximum value of $P=ab+bc+ca$

I tried to use: $(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)=(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)-abc \implies  P=\frac{1+abc}{a+b+c}$ but I am stuck. Can anyone help me? Thank you!

I'm just 14 years old, so don't use derivative or something like that (my brother uses it but I cant understand).

Comment: This feels like AGM is hiding in here somewhere, but I'm not quite sure where.

Comment: Who asked you as 14 years old this question, and, in what context, or how did you came across it?  I feel it may have a probabilistic approach...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $(a + b)(b + c)(c + a) = (a + b + c)(ab + bc + ca) - abc$ which results in
$$P = \frac{1 + abc}{a + b + c}.$$

Using AM-GM, we have
$$(a + b)(b + c)(c + a)
\ge 2\sqrt{ab}\cdot 2\sqrt{bc}\cdot 2\sqrt{ca} = 8abc$$
and
$$(a + b)(b + c)(c + a)\le \left(\frac{a + b + b + c + c + a}{3}\right)^3 = \frac{8}{27}(a + b + c)^3.$$

Thus, we have
$abc \le 1/8$ and $a + b + c\ge 3/2$.

Thus, we have
$$P = \frac{1 + abc}{a + b + c} \le \frac{1 + 1/8}{3/2} = 3/4.$$

Also, when $a = b = c = 1/2$,
we have $(a + b)(b + c)(c + a) = 1$ and $P = 3/4$.

Thus, the maximum of $P$ is $3/4$.

Comment: I like it, but, sorry to ask: can you, perhaps in your answer, elaborate on how $P=ab+bc+ca$ turns into $P = \frac{1 + abc}{a + b + c}$?

Comment: The OP said they already had.  $(a+b)(b+c)(a+c) = (a+b+c)(ab+ ac + bc)- abc = 1$ The middle is just multiplying out the LHS and factoring and the RHS is given.  Then isolating what we want to find $(ab + ac + bc) = \frac {1+abc}{a+b+c}$

Comment: @DougM thanks and: OOPS, sorry so much!

Comment: @FirstNameLastName Thanks. I edited it.

Comment: @DougM Thanks for that.

Comment: Ohh, thank you so much for this solution

Comment: @Jnote You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

For any numbers $x, y, z > 0$, the [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) gives
$$
\frac{x + y + z}{3} \ge \sqrt[3]{xyz},
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
 (x + y + z)^3 \ge 27 xyz,
$$
where equality holds if and only if $x = y = z$.

Setting $x = a + b$, $y = b + c$, $z = c + a$, we get
$x + y + z = 2a + 2b + 2c$, so
$$
(2a + 2b + 2c)^3 \ge 27 \cdot (a + b)(b + c)(c + a) = 27,
$$
so
$$
2a + 2b + 2c \ge \sqrt[3]{27} = 3,
$$
giving
$$
a + b + c \ge \frac{3}{2},
$$
where equality holds if and only if $a + b = b + c = c + a$;
that is, $a = b = c = \frac{1}{2}$.

Setting $x = a$, $y = b$, $z = c$, we get
$$
abc \le \frac{1}{27} \cdot (a + b + c)^3,
$$
where equality holds if and only if $a = b = c$.

Therefore, as you have calculated,
$$
P = \frac{1 + abc}{a + b + c}
\le \frac{1 + \frac{1}{27} (a + b + c)^3}{a + b + c}
= \frac{(a + b + c)^2}{27} + \frac{1}{a + b + c}
$$
where equality holds if and only if $a = b = c = \frac{1}{2}$.

Let
$$
f(x) = \frac{x^2}{27} + \frac{1}{x}.
$$
To determine the minimum point of $f$ without derivatives, we apply the AM-GM inequality again.  When $x > 0$,
$$
f(x) = \frac{x^2}{27} + \frac{1}{2x} + \frac{1}{2x}
\ge 3 \cdot \sqrt[3]{\frac{x^2}{27} \cdot \frac{1}{2x} \cdot \frac{1}{2x}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{4}},
$$
where equality holds if and only if $\frac{x^2}{27} = \frac{1}{2x} = \frac{1}{2x}$; that is, $x = \frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{2}}$.

For any $0 < x < y$,
$$
f(x) - f(y)
= \frac{x^2 - y^2}{27} + \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y}
= \frac{(x+y)(x-y)}{27} - \frac{x - y}{xy}
= \frac{(x-y)(x^2 y + x y^2 - 27)}{27xy}.
$$
When $0 < x < y \le \frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{2}}$,
$$
x^2 y + x y^2 - 27 < \frac{27}{2} + \frac{27}{2} - 27 = 0,
$$
so $f(x) > f(y)$.
Similarly, when $\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{2}} \le x < y$
$f(x) < f(y)$.
In other words,
$f$ is decreasing on $(0, \frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{2}})$
and increasing on $(\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{2}}, +\infty)$.

Now we consider two cases.

(1) If $\frac{3}{2} \le a + b + c \le 3$
(note that $\frac{3}{2} < \frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{2}} < 3$),
then
$$
P \le f(a + b + c) \le \max\{f(\tfrac{3}{2}), f(3)\}
= \max\{\tfrac{3}{4}, \tfrac{2}{3}\} = \tfrac{3}{4},
$$
where equality holds if and only if $a + b + c = \frac{3}{2}$,
which in turn holds if and only if $a = b = c = \frac{3}{2}$.

(2) If $a + b + c > 3$,
then at least one of $a$, $b$, and $c$ is greater than $1$.
Assume without loss of generality that $c > 1$.
Since
$$
a + b = \frac{1}{(a + c)(b + c)} < \frac{1}{c^2},
$$
we have
$$
c > 3 - (a + b) > 3 - \frac{1}{c^2} > 2,
$$
so $a + b < \frac{1}{4}$.
Hence,
$$
ab \le \biggl(\frac{a + b}{2}\biggr)^2 < \frac{1}{64}
$$
by the AM-GM inequality.
Therefore,
$$
P = \frac{1}{a + b + c} + \frac{abc}{a + b + c}
< \frac{2}{3} + \frac{\frac{1}{64} c}{c}
= \frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{64} < \frac{3}{4}
$$
(note that $a + b + c > c$).

Combining the two cases, we conclude that $P \le \frac{3}{4}$,
where equality holds if and only if $a = b = c = \frac{1}{2}$.

---

Here is a more brute-force approach using [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier).  We seek to maximize the [$C^1$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness#Differentiability_classes) $\def\RR{\mathbb{R}} f \colon \RR^3 \to \RR$ defined by
$$
f(a, b, c) = ab + bc + ca
$$
given the constraint $g(a, b, c) = 0$,
where the $C^1$ function $g \colon \RR^3 \to \RR$ is defined by
$$
g(a, b, c) = (a + b)(b + c)(c + a) - 1.
$$
The gradients of $f$ and $g$ are
$$
\nabla f(a, b, c) = \begin{bmatrix} b + c \\ c + a \\ a + b \end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
\nabla g(a, b, c) = \begin{bmatrix}
    (b + c)(2a + b + c) \\
    (c + a)(2b + c + a) \\
    (a + b)(2c + a + b)
\end{bmatrix} \neq \mathbf{0}.
$$
For an optimal solution $(a, b, c)$, there is a unique Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$ such that $\nabla f(a, b, c) = \lambda \nabla g(a, b, c)$, i.e.,
$$
\begin{bmatrix} b + c \\ c + a \\ a + b \end{bmatrix}
= \lambda \begin{bmatrix}
    (b + c)(2a + b + c) \\
    (c + a)(2b + c + a) \\
    (a + b)(2c + a + b)
\end{bmatrix},
$$
so
$$
2a + b + c = 2b + c + a = 2c + a + b = \frac{1}{\lambda}
$$
(note that $\lambda > 0$),
hence $a = b = c$.
But $g(a, b, c) = 0$,
so $(2a)^3 = 1$,
hence $a = b = c = \frac{1}{2}$,
and $\lambda = \frac{1}{2}$.

The [bordered Hessian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix#Bordered_Hessian) is
$$
\begin{multline}
\mathbf{H}(\lambda, a, b, c) \\
= \begin{bmatrix}
0                   & (b + c)(2a + b + c) & (c + a)(2b + c + a) & (a + b)(2c + a + b) \\
(b + c)(2a + b + c) & - 2 \lambda (b + c) & 1 - 2 \lambda (a + b + c) & 1 - 2 \lambda (a + b + c) \\
(c + a)(2b + c + a) & 1 - 2 \lambda (a + b + c) & - 2 \lambda (c + a) & 1 - 2 \lambda (a + b + c) \\
(a + b)(2c + a + b) & 1 - 2 \lambda (a + b + c) & 1 - 2 \lambda (a + b + c) & - 2 \lambda (a + b) \\
\end{bmatrix},
\end{multline}
$$
so
$$
\mathbf{H}(\tfrac12, \tfrac12, \tfrac12, \tfrac12)
= \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
2 & - 1 & -\tfrac12 & -\tfrac12 \\
2 & -\tfrac12 & - 1 & -\tfrac12 \\
2 & -\tfrac12 & -\tfrac12 & - 1 \\
\end{bmatrix},
$$
whose 3rd and 4th leading principal minors have determinants
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 2 & 2 \\
2 & - 1 & -\tfrac12 \\
2 & -\tfrac12 & - 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} = 4 > 0
$$
and
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
2 & - 1 & -\tfrac12 & -\tfrac12 \\
2 & -\tfrac12 & - 1 & -\tfrac12 \\
2 & -\tfrac12 & -\tfrac12 & - 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} = -3 < 0.
$$
Therefore, $a = b = c = \frac{1}{2}$ is a local maximum point,
and hence the optimal solution to the optimization problem.

Comment: thank you so muchh

Comment: sorry, The line $abc \le \frac{1}{27} \cdot (a + b + c)^3 = \frac{1}{27} \cdot \biggl(\frac{3}{2}\biggr)^3 = \frac{1}{8}$ make me confuse. Cause, $ \frac{3}{2} \le a+b+c$, not $\frac{2}{3}=a+b+c$, right? So it seem sth was wrong

Comment: @Jnote You are right, the direction of the inequality was reversed there.  I will fix the answer in a moment

Comment: @Jnote I have edited the answer to fix the problem.  Now it looks much less elegant, though, as I had to analyze the properties of the function $f(x) = \frac{x^2}{27} + \frac{1}{x}$ and discharge the case $a + b + c > 3$.  I hope to see a more elegant solution.

Comment: Thank you so much